# kvm networking trunk vlan

Tags: linux, centos, kvm, rhel

Здравствуйте!

Имеем физический сервер с 3 сетевыми картами, на две из которых подан trunk с 20 vlan внутри.

Как подать в определенную гостевую ОС конкретный транк, но не привязывать интерфейс к конкретному адресу?

Comment: Нужно чуть больше информации. Порт нужно подать в гостевую ось в access mode? или несколько влан сразу в одну ось?

Answer (score 0):

Подскажи зачем "не привязывать"? Расскажу подробней.

Обычно делают bond на эти 2 интерфейса, поднимаешь на бонде вланы, а виртуалкам выдаёшь мактап на определенный влан (например, bond0.12).